# Define sci-kit Pipeline to account for unknown test data

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am getting the following error when trying to make prediction on unknown test data using a loaded `pkl` model in `sci-kit learn`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

/Users/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.pyc in decision_function(self, X)
    315         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
    316             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
--> 317                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
    318 
    319         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 10000
```

I have followed the instructions from other similar `stack overflow` posts, such as [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32106063/sklearn-linearsvc-x-has-1-features-per-sample-expecting-5), [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233156/python-scikit-svm-valueerror-x-has-62-features-per-sample-expecting-337) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31744519/load-pickled-classifier-data-vocabulary-not-fitted-error), and I have implemented the `Pipeline` feature to ensure that I am using the same paramters, however, I am still receiving the same error as when I created a separate `vectorizer` for the test data instead of using the `pipeline`.
How can I convert my unknown test data into an adequate matrix using my previously trained and saved loaded model?
Is there a function in `sci-kit learn` that I am not using here?

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# ingests train data

data = pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0, sep=',', names=['sentiment', 'review'])
X_train = data["review"]
y_train = data["sentiment"]

# trains and saves models with pipeline


text_log_reg = Pipeline([('count_vect', CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",
                             tokenizer = None,
                             preprocessor = None,
                             stop_words = None,
                             max_features = 10000)),
                    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
                    ('log_reg', LogisticRegression()),
                    ])

text_log_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
results2 = text_log_reg.predict(X_train)

_ = joblib.dump(text_log_reg, 'log_reg-SA-1,pkl', compress=9)

# uses loaded model to make predictions

dataTest = pd.read_csv('test.csv', 
                   header=None, sep=',', names=['review'])

X_test = dataTest["review"]

print '----load classifier model----'
clf = joblib.load('log_reg-SA-1,pkl')

predicted = clf.predict(X_test) 
print predicted
```

Sample data:
`train.csv`

```
"id","review","score"
"123","I love movies","1"
"456","I hate movies","0"
"789","That show was great","1"
"012","He makes the plot interesting","1"
"345","The ending made me sleep","0"
```

`test.csv`

```
"id","review"
"678","I loved the plot of that show"
"910","I dislike the main character"
```

Comment: you're saving `log_reg-SA-1,pkl` but loading `log_reg-1,pkl`. Maybe that's the problem =). Your code sample also has some undefined variables like `clean_train_reviews` and `log_reg_fit`, so it won't work.

Comment: You have to use the same vectorizer you used during training. You cannot train on apples and then predict cars. In your case features seem to be words, you should ignore words not present during training for testing.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I am using the same vectorizer through the defined `Pipeline`. @gereleth I tried to anonymize the code and forgot to change some parts. I just edited the question to reflect.

Comment: Is there a reason you first define a `count_vect` but then pass a `CountVectorizer()` to the pipeline?

Comment: It seems that is not transforming your data. Could you try `X_test = clf.transform(X_test)` just before the predict call? (I would assume that predict should take care of this, but doesnt seem to be the case from the error message). Doest it work if you just use it without doig joblib dump/load?

Comment: @ImanolLuengo I just tried that. I get the following error: `ValueError: X has different number of features than during model fitting.`. To note, there is also the following warning `DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  DeprecationWarning)` There is definitely a problem with transformation, I just can't identify

Comment: @gereleth i have edited and updated code in question to reflect your concern.

Comment: `import TfidfVectorizer` should probably be `import TfidfTransformer`. Also, taking the code and sample data as now presented but swapping your use of 'sentiment' and 'review' seems both to run and make more sense than predicting the text from the score, which gives `AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'lower'`. If doing so is correct though, there's still a problem: this runs all the way through – the sample data doesn't appear to reproduce your issue. **Edit:** Needs one additional change: `names=['sentiment', 'review']` when loading `dataTest`.

Comment: @EFT Do you suggest swapping those attributes? My objective is to calculate the score from the text. I also updated code accordingly to your comments. In the test data, which is what I am having a problem with transforming - there is no score.

Comment: train names should be `['review', 'sentiment']`, and the code works for me with no issues.

Comment: If you're not getting either the error in my comment or maybe something like `ValueError: empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words` if it interprets the score as a string somehow, then your actual dataset is different enough from the sample that I'm cautious of recommending changes. Otherwise yes.

Comment: @EFT for the tests that I am doing, my train and test data is what I am showing above. The error after switching the `review` and `sentiment` train names that I am getting is now the following: `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: Using exactly what is shown in the Question currently (Edit #8) but with full quotes around `123` in `train.csv` and `678` in `test.csv` & including @gereleth's suggestion, which is the most straightforward method, for swapping them?

Comment: @EFT yes, with those changes the error that I am now finding is `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`
"

Comment: That's odd. That's the error I get with `names=['sentiment', 'review']` in train. What is the output if you `print data`?

Comment: @EFT your suggestions have helped me solve the problem, see updated and edited code. With the full quotes and switching the attributes, I am able to load and use the saved model.